# Resizing both height and width textInput in kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

```
<AutoResizedText>
GridLayout:
    cols:1
    size: root.width, root.height
    TextInput:
        multiline:True
        size_hint:(None,None)
        size:(self.height,self.minimum_height )
        text: "hello my cat"
```

I'm currently trying to get a TextInput that expands in width and height based upon what string it contains within it. I've been able to get the height to expand alongside the text. But not the width for some reason. self.minimum_width does not appear to be a method when I try to replace self.height with self.minimum_height

Answer (score 1):

The `TextInput` can't do what you want without some modifications. The standard `TextInput` needs you to set the width, then it will fill its text field, splitting the text as needed to keep it to that width, and calculating a minimum_height based on that.

Here is a version of `TextInput` that I have modified to do what I think you want:

```
class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    minimum_width = NumericProperty(0)

    def _split_smart(self, text):
        # modified to always split on newline only
        lines = text.split(u'\n')
        lines_flags = [0] + [FL_IS_LINEBREAK] * (len(lines) - 1)
        return lines, lines_flags

    def _refresh_text(self, text, *largs):
        # this is modified slightly just to calculate minimum_width

        # Refresh all the lines from a new text.
        # By using cache in internal functions, this method should be fast.
        mode = 'all'
        if len(largs) > 1:
            mode, start, finish, _lines, _lines_flags, len_lines = largs
            # start = max(0, start)
            cursor = None
        else:
            cursor = self.cursor_index()
            _lines, self._lines_flags = self._split_smart(text)
        _lines_labels = []
        _line_rects = []
        _create_label = self._create_line_label

        # calculate minimum width
        min_width = 0
        for x in _lines:
            lbl = _create_label(x)
            min_width = max(min_width, lbl.width)
            _lines_labels.append(lbl)
            _line_rects.append(Rectangle(size=lbl.size))
        self.minimum_width = min_width + self.padding[0] + self.padding[2]

        if mode == 'all':
            self._lines_labels = _lines_labels
            self._lines_rects = _line_rects
            self._lines = _lines
        elif mode == 'del':
            if finish > start:
                self._insert_lines(start,
                                   finish if start == finish else (finish + 1),
                                   len_lines, _lines_flags,
                                   _lines, _lines_labels, _line_rects)
        elif mode == 'insert':
            self._insert_lines(
                start,
                finish if (start == finish and not len_lines)
                else (finish + 1),
                len_lines, _lines_flags, _lines, _lines_labels,
                _line_rects)

        min_line_ht = self._label_cached.get_extents('_')[1]
        # with markup texture can be of height `1`
        self.line_height = max(_lines_labels[0].height, min_line_ht)
        # self.line_spacing = 2
        # now, if the text change, maybe the cursor is not at the same place as
        # before. so, try to set the cursor on the good place
        row = self.cursor_row
        self.cursor = self.get_cursor_from_index(self.cursor_index()
                                                 if cursor is None else cursor)
        # if we back to a new line, reset the scroll, otherwise, the effect is
        # ugly
        if self.cursor_row != row:
            self.scroll_x = 0
        # with the new text don't forget to update graphics again
        self._trigger_update_graphics()

    def on_text(self, *args):
        # added to update minimum width on each change
        cc, cr = self.cursor
        text = self._lines[cr]
        lbl = self._create_line_label(text)
        self.minimum_width = max(self.minimum_width, lbl.width + self.padding[0] + self.padding[2])
```

This version of `TextInput` has a `minimum_width` property. I have modified `_smart_split()` so that it only splits lines on newlines. The `_refresh_text()` is almost identical to the original, but includes a calculation of `minimum_width`. I added a `on_text()` method to update `minimum_width` each time the `text` changes. So, now you can use `self.minimum_width` and `self.minimum_height` to size the `Widget` as:

```
MyTextInput:
    multiline: True
    size_hint:(None,None)
    size:(self.minimum_width, self.minimum_height)
    text: "hello my cat"
```

Comment: is FL_IS_LINEBREAK defined somewhere else or am I just compiling this wrong?

Comment: It is defined in `TextInput`, so you need an import like: `from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput, FL_IS_LINEBREAK`.